# HDF5 Library mismatch

Tags: python, hdf5

Can any Python gurus help me solve this error? Getting a HDF5 Library mismatch error.

The problem is that by default when I install h5py

```
pip install h5py
```

it also installs latest HDF5 dependency which is 1.10.2.
My application apparently requires an earlier version, 1.8.11.

My complete error

```
>  Warning! ***HDF5 library version mismatched error*** The HDF5 header
> files used to compile this application do not match the version used
> by the HDF5 library to which this application is linked. Data
> corruption or segmentation faults may occur if the application
> continues. This can happen when an application was compiled by one
> version of HDF5 but linked with a different version of static or
> shared HDF5 library. You should recompile the application or check
> your shared library related settings such as 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH'. You
> can, at your own risk, disable this warning by setting the environment
> variable 'HDF5_DISABLE_VERSION_CHECK' to a value of '1'. Setting it to
> 2 or higher will suppress the warning messages totally. Headers are
> 1.10.2, library is 1.8.11
>         SUMMARY OF THE HDF5 CONFIGURATION
>         =================================
> 
> General Information:
> -------------------
>            HDF5 Version: 1.8.11
>           Configured on: Sun Jul 24 12:04:33 EDT 2016
>           Configured by: prisms@sikasso
>          Configure mode: production
>             Host system: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
```

etc, etc

Comment: Install from source, to have it built with your system version (http://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/build.html#source-installation). Remember that for debian like system you will need the dev version of the library of `hdf5` and `python` (http://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/build.html#source-installation-on-linux-other-unix)

Comment: Most applications using HDF5 1.8.x can be rebuilt using HDF5 1.10.x. Could you try to rebuild you application? Do you use C or Fortran codes with HDF5 or is h5py your only interface to HDF5?